# How can I use Perl 5 modules from Perl 6?

Tags: perl, cpan, raku, rakudo

Is the a way to use Perl 5 modules from CPAN from Rakudo Perl 6?

For example, how can I use the venerable Perl 5 module, CGI, which hasn't been ported yet, in Perl 6.

**Update:**

And what this funky code from some early Perl 6 module:

```
use CGI:from<perl5>;
```

Is the `:from<perl5>` directive used to evoke some kind of a Perl 5 compatibility layer? Can't seem to find any documentation about it.

Comment: I understand CGI is just a example, but for modern web development you could look [Dancer for Perl6](http://ttjjss.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/state-of-dancer-on-perl-6)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are perl5 libraries are importable in perl6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382133/are-perl5-libraries-are-importable-in-perl6)

Comment: Like @w.k., I understand CGI is just an example, but, like them, I also want to mention a native Raku option for web dev, though in my case it's from the perspective of late 2019: [Cro](https://cro.services/).

Answer (score 10):

Use [Inline::Perl5](https://github.com/niner/Inline-Perl5).

---

The following example shows how to use the CPAN hosted Perl 5 module `Text::Unidecode` ("the Unicode transliteration of last resort") in Raku.

First, install Inline::Perl5 if you don't already have it installed:

```
zef install Inline::Perl5
```

Now install the CPAN module if you don't already have it installed:

```
perl -MCPAN -e "install Text::Unidecode"
```

You can now use the installed Perl module by writing a `use` statement with an appended `:from<Perl5>` (with an uppercase `P`, not `:from<perl5>`) :

```
use Text::Unidecode:from<Perl5>;
say Text::Unidecode::unidecode 'Solidarność';
```

displays:

```
Solidarnosc
```

See also [other SO posts about Inline::Perl5](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=inline%3A%3Aperl5+%5Braku%5D+or+%5Bperl6%5D).

Comment: @raiph I added your comment to the answer, feel free to edit it further

Comment: When I try to install Inline::Perl5 it says it can't find resources\libraries\p5helper.dll

Answer (score 0):

There is [blizkost](https://github.com/jnthn/blizkost) project that aims to use of perl5 code from Rakudo/Parrot. However it is AFAIK in quite early stage of development and probably not usable for real code.

Comment: The last commit was more than a year ago.

Comment: @BradGilbert - yeah, thats why I put the warning there. However this is only project I know of that aims at using perl5 in parrot.

Comment: @bvr Parrot for Perl6 is also kind of dead. Rakudo FTF! (for the future)