# Are perl5 libraries are importable in perl6?

Tags: perl, raku

I know that perl6 will definetely allow importing perl5 code but I'm not able to do this.

Here is perl6 [code](https://github.com/perl6/mu/blob/master/examples/perl5/cpan-upload.pl)

```
use perl5:Net::FTP;
```

It reports an [error](http://ideone.com/zWi8pN)

Is there any configuration issue or it is not ready yet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use Perl 5 modules from Perl 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173043/how-can-i-use-perl-5-modules-from-perl-6)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [Inline::Perl5](https://github.com/niner/Inline-Perl5/blob/master/README.md) to embed arbitrary Perl code in Raku or `use` Perl libraries as if they were Raku libraries.

Inline::Perl5 appropriately packages and wraps a regular perl interpreter in [MoarVM](http://moarvm.com) so that Rakudo can interop with Perl. The combination already supports:

- `use`ing Perl modules, including ones that use XS, in Raku
- Using Perl objects in Raku and vice-versa
- Writing, in Raku, sub-classes of Perl classes

nine, the author of the Inline::Perl5 module, has done some presentations about it and its use that are available on youtube:

- A 3 minute [lightning talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_Y-lvQP6jI&list=UU7PuZDAIVMyE7mgkZHunXGw) about Inline::Perl5 that nine presented the day after the project began in 2014;
- [Longer presentations](http://www.reddit.com/r/perl6/comments/2k6ii8/nines_apw_talk_demonstrating_fully_working/) about Inline::Perl5.

Answer (score 1):

<s>According to [perlwiki](http://wiki.perl6.org/module)</s>

> note: As of May 2012, none of the Perl 6 compilers yet implement this feature.

According to [adventcalendar](http://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2013/12/16/day-16-slangs/)

Some basic modules are usable through slang feature but only a few of them like Config, Cwd and English are available.